# Template processing, string repeat {{repeat 5}}

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have following cases

Input

```
var str = '{{repeat 2}} some string {{/repeat}}';
```

Output

```
str = 'some string, some string';
```

---

Input

```
var str = '{{repeat 2}}{"prop1":"some data"}{{/repeat}}';
```

Output

```
str = '{"prop1":"some data"}, {"prop1":"some data"}';
```

---

Input

```
var str = 'start of string {{repeat 2}} some string {{/repeat}} another string ';
```

Output

```
str = 'start of string some string, some string another string';
```

I was thinking to do this way

```
var test = "{{repeat 5}} test this string {{/repeat}}";
var arrStr = test.split(/[{{]/);
```

and processing this by looping `arrStr`

Any other good approach to do this ? How to find the repeat with repeat count and string inside the repeat ?

Comment: `/[{{]/` is equivalent to `/[{]/` and to `/\{/`. This is a character class, not a sequence of characters.

Comment: @Xufox I want only to get {{repeat

Comment: This looks like an attempt to create your own string templating engine. Point #1: You probably don't want to write a templating engine. Use an existing one, there are quite a few great choices. ("but I only need this little feature" is not an acceptable counter-argument) Point #2: You probably don't want to write a templating language parser that is based on regex. That's a waste of time, it will not work. If you want to do it properly, you need a tokenizer, a parser, a compiler, etc. [peg.js](https://pegjs.org/) can help you with that. You can do that, but others already have, see point #1.

Comment: @Shafeeq: If you need to find all paired repeats, use a loop, see https://jsfiddle.net/7ga26vrk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace the texts inside a replace callback:

```js
function fillArray(s, num) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
    arr.push(s);
  }
  return arr;
}
var str = 'start of string {{repeat 2}} some string {{/repeat}} another string ';
var res = str.replace(/{{repeat\s+(\d+)}}([\s\S]*?){{\/repeat}}/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
  return fillArray($2.trim(), parseInt($1, 10)).join(", ");
});
console.log(res);
```

The `fillArray` function creates an array with the necessary number of the extract string occurrences.

The regex to get what you need looks like

```
/{{repeat\s+(\d+)}}([\s\S]*?){{\/repeat}}/g
```

**Details**:

- `{{repeat` - a literal char sequence
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `}}` - literal `}}`
- `([\s\S]*?)` -  Group 2, any 0+ characters, as few as possible up to the first
- `{{\/repeat}}` - literal `{{/repeat}}`.

Comment: This will not work with constructs like `{{repeat 2}} this is a {{repeat 2}} doubled {{/repeat}} text {{/repeat}}`. Regex simply are not a good way to approach this task.

Answer (score 1):

The [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) might be what you are interested in.
As it just repeats the string without the comma, the following would also do that for you:

```
function repeatString(s, count) {
  return (s + ", ").repeat(count).replace(/,\s$/, "");
}
```

Now you can use that like

```js
function repeatString(s, count) {
  return (s + ", ").repeat(count).replace(/,\s$/, "");
}

var s = "some string";
var res = "start of string " + repeatString(s, 2) + " other string";

console.log(res);
```

Note that `repeat()` isn't supported by all browsers at the time of writing this, but you can use the [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill)

---

If you get your string from html or something with the {{repeat...}} already in, the following would do the trick:

```js
function repeatString(s) {
  var count = s.match(/\{\{repeat\s(\d*)\}\}/)[1];
  return (s.replace(/\{\{repeat\s\d*\}\}\s(.*)\s\{\{\/repeat\}\}/, "$1") + ", ").repeat(count).replace(/,\s$/, "");
}

var s = "{{repeat 5}} some string {{/repeat}}";
var res = "start of string " + repeatString(s) + " other string";

console.log(res);
```

Worth to mention that there are many many html template engines already available as open-source projects. In most cases it's a good idea to use one of them instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This would help me to repeat the string, finding the {{repeat  is something I have stuck in

Comment: You don't need to find the {{ by using this @Shafeeq

Comment: for me input is like {{repeat 5}} some string {{/repeat}}

Comment: New edited answer almost near to expectation only difference is for me the input is  'start of string {{repeat 2}} some string {{/repeat}} another string '. Thanks anyway let try to use ur functionality

Comment: Edited again @Shafeeq, now it should be what you wanted, right?

Comment: May be Im bad at explaining my requirement, my question description isn't  enough to explain my requirement, I have a string which may contain multiple repeat like this 'Aaaa {{repeat 2}} bbbb {{/repeat}} Ccc {{repeat 5}} ddd {{/repeat}} eee'